# template operator specialization with =

Tags: c++, templates, generics, g++

I'm trying to implement this template operator specialization

```
template <class T>
class test
{
public:
  T value;
};


template <> test &test::operator=<std::string>(const char *rhs)
{ return *this;}
```

But with g++, I get this error :

> error: invalid use of template-name 'test' without an argument list 
>   template <> test &test::operator=(const char *rhs)
>                ^~~~

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, the error message underlines exactly the problematic code.

Comment: You need the primary template declaration before specialization.

Comment: Ok, now it is minimal, complete and verifiable !

Comment: @songyuanyao ok, but do you have an example ?

Comment: `test` is a template, not a type.It has to be `test<something>` in your definition. And where is the operator declared in the first place?

Comment: @Stef http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/S4tl6AR1MVWIVVGC

Comment: @Stef your compile is not MCVE because it does not compile. We should be able to copy/paste your example into a blank file and compile it.

Comment: Mhh, of course it doesn't compile... That is my problem :)

Comment: FWIW: a MCVE does not require the code to compile, just to have enough that we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've simply placed the template parameter in the wrong place. A templated class needs template arguments outside of it's scope, so in this case the return type also needs template arguments.

```
template<class T>
class test
{
public:
    test & operator=(const char * rhs) {
        return *this;
    }
};

template<> test<std::string> & test<std::string>::operator=(const char * rhs) { 
// type goes here ^^^^^^^^^ and here ^^^^^^^^^^ 
    return *this; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, It works... But I don't understand why I get downvotes !?

Comment: @Stef people downvote questions that do not provide [short compilable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your example does not compile. If you copy/paste it directly into a blank file, the only compiler errors should be the ones the question is asking about.

Comment: @Stef: You never defined the base function, so how did you expect to specialize it?